# Validate signature from public key, automatically detect algorithm in BouncyCastle

Tags: .net, digital-signature, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption, asn.1

My question is: how can I write my signature validation function to be agnostic of the public key algorithm?

I'm working with .Net's BouncyCastle library (v1.8.4). I'm trying to validate a signature without knowing the algorithm in advance (but it's identification will be embedded in the public key).

I need to verify the signature for a byte stream and I've got the public key in PEM format:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE7t7Uo4NB7kjqPGMzdXbBI66gy8rz
oYvRatFPTGsdS9lCru6imfdMclcr/hCkxHgfgz0ewmKqEjWK8EjZczUCEA==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I expect it to inform the algorithm within the ASN.1 stream, which in this example parses like this:

```
$ openssl asn1parse -i -in pubkey.pem
    0:d=0  hl=2 l=  89 cons: SEQUENCE
    2:d=1  hl=2 l=  19 cons:  SEQUENCE
    4:d=2  hl=2 l=   7 prim:   OBJECT            :id-ecPublicKey
   13:d=2  hl=2 l=   8 prim:   OBJECT            :prime256v1
   23:d=1  hl=2 l=  66 prim:  BIT STRING
```

The algoritm is in this case is prime256v1 (secp256k1, etc.), but I won't know what is it in advance. Currently, my code looks like this:

```vb
Private Function SignatureChecks(data() as Byte, pubkey as String, signature as String) As Boolean

    Dim keypars As Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricKeyParameter 'impements ICipherParameters

    'Read and parse the PEM file into the proper object
    Dim pubkeybytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pubkey)
    Using pubkeystream = New MemoryStream(pubkeybytes)
        Using reader = New StreamReader(pubkeystream)
            Dim pemrd = New PemReader(reader)
            'Now this is the decoded PEM for the public key
            keypars = pemrd.ReadObject()
        End Using
    End Using

    Dim signer As ISigner

    '*************************************************************
    'Currently this is hardwired: how can I make this intelligent?
    '*************************************************************
    signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA-256withECDSA")

    'Init the signer with the public key
    signer.Init(False, keypars)
    'Appends the data to be verified in the SHA block buffer
    signer.BlockUpdate(data, 0, data.Length)

    'Get the bytes from the signature
    Dim sigbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(signature)

    Return signer.VerifySignature(sigbytes)

End Function
```

This code works fine, as long as the signature was made using the secp256k1 algorithm, which might not be the case. I've tried extracting the info from the AsymmetricKeyParameter object (which is actually an ECPublicKeyParameters), but it has very few public members. However, the relevant information does show in the internals of the object using the debugger: values like publicKeyParamSet=1.2.840.10045.3.1.7, algorithm="EC", etc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `prime256v1` algorithm informed in the public key is just the *encryption* algorithm (as it should be), while no *hash* algorithm is specified in either the public key or the signature. To verify the signature, a hash function (in this case SHA-256) must be agreed between the actors using other means. An example is CMS encoding (formerly PKCS#7), which is a container method that can embed all the information required to check the signature validity. Obtaining the encryption algorithm from the public key is not sufficient for performing the task.